# problem: java: how to get values from double array to string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays

```
double[] pole=new double[100];
XSSFRichTextString[] pole1=new XSSFRichTextString[100];
```

array "pole" I filled like this

```
XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: {
pole[i] = cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

Is there a simple way how to write values from "pole" to "pole1"?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XSSFRichTextString[] pole1=new XSSFRichTextString[pole.length];
int peakLimit= pole.length;
for(int i = 0 ; i < peakLimit ; i++){
  //Apply here conversion logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pole1[i] = new XSSFRichTextString(""+pole[i]);
```